# Is there any possible way to get TimeZone by ZipCode in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a list of around 400 zip codes. I need to use this code's time zone in the application. For Example:- If my code zip code 35242, after googling I found the time zone for 35242 is GMT-5. Now in the application, I need to add `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5)`. Is there any way to do this from code or do I have to search the timezone for all zip codes and do it manually?

Comment: *.Net*  has no understanding of what a *zipcode* is. You will have to build something yourself, or you might be lucky enough to find a library (you never know your luck)

Comment: It seems there is no direct way thru you can get a time zone by zip code. It can done using some third-party service OR custom table in DB with a combination of your zip code and time zone.

Comment: Note that the `[asp.net]` and `[asp.net-mvc]` tags are for .NET Framework. If you're using .NET Core you should use `[asp.net-core]` and `[asp.net-core-mvc]` instead. Anyway, in this case they aren't relevant to the question, so I've removed them.

Comment: [First Google result for "zip code to timezone csv"](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/ZIP-Code-Time-Zones/prodview-4vcapflqwntdw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Is there any way to get time zone from zip code programmatically?

A: Sure. There are lots of databases, programming libraries and web services available.  Some paid, some free; some "static" (e.g. a .csv download), others dynamic (e.g. a REST API).

SUGGESTION: Consider trying Google's [Timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

- [Getting started with Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started)
- [Getting started with Google TimeZone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/get-started)
- [C#/VB/Net example code](https://googlemapcontrol.com/tag/example-code/)